How to store values in case of a dynamic batch size?
I have included the "batchForTrain" block in my simulation model. However, the batch size is set dynamic as follows:
(int) triangular(50, 55, 60)
Now each time new batch is formed, I want to store the exact value of the batch size.
I don't know, how?
BATCH BLOCK PROPERTIES
I tried to use collections, but couldn't do it successfully.

pls only use the "anylogic" tab, that suffices

No need to store it, your batched Container agent already knows about it. All batched agents are callable via the .contents() function. You can use contents().size() to get the number of batched agents.
So simply call that on a Container instance and you get how many have been batched together. Loop across contents() to get a list of the actual batched agents.
It is right in the help:

